# Check if value of a cell is available in another sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

Alright so I have a question and need assistance.

I need to check if the value on cell A1 (sheet 1) is available in coloumn 1 (sheet 2). If YES, cell A2 (sheet 2) should turn green, if NO, cell A2 (sheet 2) should remain blank/colourless.

Please help me on this at the soonest.

Thanks,
Ibrahim

Answer (score 1):

In cell A2 on Sheet2, put in the formula:

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!Range,1,FALSE),0)

**Range: As you want it.** Eg. A1: A100, A1: A10000 etc

**Explanation:**
*The **Vlookup** formula is used to see if the value in A1 is in the range you selected on Sheet2. **IfError** is to put in the value of 0 in case the value isn't there in Column1 of Sheet2*

On cell A2 now, Goto Home> Conditional formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Equal to > 1
Then you can select the type of color you want from the subsequent box.

Then if the value in cell A1 is in Column 1 of sheet2 you would have the color of cell A2 turning to what you had selected above.

Comment: okay the logic is working but in the new cell, if the condition is true, it puts in the text as A1. but the color logic isnt working :( please help3

Comment: In that case go Cell A2 > Conditional formatting > Manage Rules > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > Then put in the formula "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!Range,1,FALSE),0)" and select the format you want...... And you would be done. This would only give color to a cell, not the Data.

Comment: still not working :( can you add me on gmail? ill send you the sheet, please can you do it for me?.. my id is xtreamgeneration@gmail.com

Comment: hi, please help me here. i have a slight crisis on this :(

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what you mean by "available". Let's assume you mean Sheet1 / Cell A1 is a formula, and you want to ensure the formula was able to evaluate, that is, not result in a #VALUE! or other error.

Then you need a *conditional format*. Click on sheet 2, Cell A2. From the `Home` ribbon, choose `Conditional Format` -> `Manage Rules...` and choose `New Rule`. Tell Excel you want the bottom option, "Enter as the formula to decide which cells to format" then enter for the formula:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(Sheet1!$A$1))
```

and click OK. Set the format by going to the "Fill" tab, where you choose whatever color. Other variations are possible: `=ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$A$1)` to ensure cell A1 contains a number, `ISTEXT()`, etc. Is that enough detail?